# OpenAM or OpenSSO fedlets as SP and ADFS as IdP without full implementation of OpenAM or OpenSSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, openam, opensso

From what I read OpenAM or OpenSSO fedlets allow an application to act as a service provider, if so I was wondering if full implementation of the product (OpenAM or OpenSSO) is still required to have the SP use ADFS as its IdP. Anyone ever tried it?

Is it correct that Oracle has abandoned development of the OpenSSO solution?

Does anyone know of other open source federation servlets existing?

Comment: If you have a java based app you may look at Spring Security SAML extension instead of the  Fedlet as it offer better integration into existing applications. Unfortunately the Fedlet is not there yet.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr I'm no Java expert so I might be mistaken but wouldn't the Spring SAML extension lead to more work?
As I understand it:

For web SSO only, the fedlet could simply required for it to be configured (no code change needed) while for Spring extension I think it would required changes to the web application code to at least load the library.

For claim-enabling the application, both options (fedlet and Spring extension) would required changes to the application (to access the claims/assertions). I have no idea which one would required more rework to existing web application code.

Comment: Fedlet would probably need just as much application customizations as Spring's SAML extension.

Comment: the Fedlet needs  more customization of the exiting application than Spring's SAML extension, at least from my experiences with both of them

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the full implementation of OpenAM / OpenSSO to run the fedlets.

Yes - I tried it a long time ago. Yes - it works with ADFS.

No idea if OpenSSO is still being developed but I recall reading that Oracle's OpenSSO support expired in 2014 (for premium support) and expires in 2017 (for extended support).

ForgeRock used OpenSSO as the basis for OpenAM which is still being actively developed.

By fedlet, you mean client-side SAML stack - refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html)  and the links therein.

Comment: 'fedlet' is a lightweight SAML SP provided by OpenAM